# BAPI_CONVERSION_EXT2INT1 to convert external WBS element number to internal

Tags: sap-erp, sap-basis, bapi

I want to use the BAPI [BAPI_CONVERSION_EXT2INT1](https://www.sapdatasheet.org/abap/func/bapi_conversion_ext2int1.html) to convert external to internal WBS element numbers, but don't know how to fill its parameters for this.

Yes, I know I can create Z-BAPIs of other internal BAPIs to achieve this but I need to know how to use BAPI_CONVERSION_EXT2INT1 specifically, so I don't need any Z-BAPIs anymore the next time a customer wants to use that part of our software.

If you just know about BAPI_CONVERSION_EXT2INT or BBP_CONVERSION_EXT2INT you are welcome, too (they seem to be identical anyway).

**THIS WAS SOLVED NOW!**

*Also you are legally required to upvote @sandra-rossi's answer below before continuing to read.*

With BAPI_CONVERSION_INT2EXT1:

```
BAPI_CONVERSION_INT2EXT1 bapi = new BAPI_CONVERSION_INT2EXT1(destination);
SAPTable<BAPICONVRS> tblDATA = bapi.getDATAs();
BAPICONVRS data = tblDATA.newItem();
data.setOBJTYPE("BUS2031001");
data.setMETHOD("GetDetailBos");
data.setPARAMETER("QuotationHeader");
data.setFIELD("WBS_ELEM");
data.setINT_FORMAT("102882");
bapi.execute();
```

I get:

```
EXT_FORMAT=REP_S01588 0001
```

And vice versa, with BAPI_CONVERSION_EXT2INT1:

```
BAPI_CONVERSION_EXT2INT1 bapi = new BAPI_CONVERSION_EXT2INT1 (destination);
SAPTable<BAPICONVRS> tblDATA = bapi.getDATAs();
BAPICONVRS data = tblDATA.newItem();
data.setOBJTYPE("BUS2031001");
data.setMETHOD("GetDetailBos");
data.setPARAMETER("QuotationHeader");
data.setFIELD("WBS_ELEM");
data.setEXT_FORMAT("REP_S01588 0001");
bapi.execute();
```

I get:

```
INT_FORMAT=102882
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR **Apologies for the length of the answer. If you want it short, there is an ABAP program which will give you the BAPI parameter values corresponding to various criteria (like `VBAP-PS_PSP_NR`), in the chapter "How to determine the parameters for BAPI_CONVERSION_INT2EXT1 and BAPI_CONVERSION_EXT2INT1 → 1) If you don't know the Business Object Type".**

## Introduction

BAPI is part of the Business Object Type concept (`SWO1` transaction code).

`BAPI_CONVERSION_EXT2INT1` is closely integrated with the BO concept, and is originally meant to be called either **before or after** calling a "main" BAPI function module. There are many parameters, so you need to understand the BO concept I try to quickly explain hereafter.

Let's suppose you are given the Internal value of a WBS Project and you want to get its WBS Elements. You also want to obtain both the External values (the value which is shown to the users on the screens) and Internal values (the value which is stored in the database).

The main BAPI function module to get these details is `BAPI_PROJECT_GETINFO` which is intended to receive the External value of the Project ID (although the Internal value usually works too), and it returns the External values of its WBS Elements.

The logic of the program will be:

1. Convert the Internal value of the Project ID to its External value
2. Call `BAPI_PROJECT_GETINFO`
3. Convert the External values of the returned WBS Elements to their Internal values

You may obtain the External and Internal values by calling `BAPI_CONVERSION_INT2EXT1` (Internal to External) and **`BAPI_CONVERSION_EXT2INT1`** (External to Internal), before or after calling the main BAPI function module, or even for scenarios without one.

Their parameter values are easy to find if you know the BO type corresponding to the BAPI function used (e.g. `BUS2054` for `BAPI_PROJECT_GETINFO`), but difficult otherwise (hence the question) and in that case the solution is explained in the next chapter.

For information, the transaction code `SE16N` or `S416N` can be used to see the external and internal values:

[image: SE16N PRPS External and Internal values of PSPNR and POSID]

## How to determine the parameters for `BAPI_CONVERSION_INT2EXT1` and `BAPI_CONVERSION_EXT2INT1`

### 1) If you don't know the Business Object Type

Run the ABAP program below. Various input are possible, e.g. table `VBAP` and column `PS_PSP_PNR`, or table `PRPS` and column `PSPNR`, or data element  `PS_PSP_PNR`, or domain `PS_POSNR`. All are equivalent and give the same result.

```
REPORT.
DATA:
  BEGIN OF dummy_for_select_options,
    objtype       TYPE swotdv-objtype,
    objtype_id    TYPE tojtb-editelem,
    objtype_stext TYPE tojtt-stext,
    objtype_ntext TYPE tojtt-ntext,
    method        TYPE swotdv-editelem,
    parameter     TYPE swotdq-editelem,
    field         TYPE dd03l-fieldname,
  END OF dummy_for_select_options.
TABLES swotdv.

PARAMETERS tabname TYPE dd53d-tabname.
PARAMETERS fieldnam TYPE dd53d-fieldname.
PARAMETERS rollname TYPE dd04l-rollname.
PARAMETERS domname TYPE dd01l-domname.
PARAMETERS convexit TYPE dd01l-convexit.
PARAMETERS extvalue TYPE string LOWER CASE.
PARAMETERS intvalue TYPE string LOWER CASE.
PARAMETERS max_rows TYPE i DEFAULT 10.
SELECT-OPTIONS s_objtyp FOR dummy_for_select_options-objtype.
SELECT-OPTIONS s_objid  FOR dummy_for_select_options-objtype_id.
SELECT-OPTIONS s_objstx FOR dummy_for_select_options-objtype_stext.
SELECT-OPTIONS s_objntx FOR dummy_for_select_options-objtype_ntext.
SELECT-OPTIONS s_method FOR dummy_for_select_options-method.
SELECT-OPTIONS s_param FOR dummy_for_select_options-parameter.
SELECT-OPTIONS s_field FOR dummy_for_select_options-field.


DATA leng TYPE dd01l-leng.
DATA outputlen TYPE dd01l-outputlen.
DATA lowercase TYPE dd01l-lowercase.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN.

  IF tabname IS NOT INITIAL
      AND fieldnam IS NOT INITIAL.
    SELECT SINGLE rollname, domname
        FROM dd03l
        WHERE tabname = @tabname
          AND fieldname = @fieldnam
        INTO (@rollname,@domname).
    IF sy-subrc <> 0.
      MESSAGE 'Table/field not found' TYPE 'E'.
    ELSEIF rollname IS INITIAL
        OR domname IS INITIAL.
      MESSAGE 'Table/field has no data element or no domain' TYPE 'E'.
    ENDIF.
  ENDIF.

  IF rollname IS NOT INITIAL.
    SELECT SINGLE domname
        FROM dd04l
        WHERE rollname = @rollname
        INTO @domname.
    IF sy-subrc <> 0.
      MESSAGE 'Data element not found' TYPE 'E'.
    ELSEIF domname IS INITIAL.
      MESSAGE 'Data element has no domain' TYPE 'E'.
    ENDIF.
  ENDIF.

  IF domname IS NOT INITIAL.
    SELECT SINGLE convexit, leng, outputlen, lowercase
        FROM dd01l
        WHERE domname = @domname
        INTO (@convexit,@leng,@outputlen,@lowercase).
    IF sy-subrc <> 0.
      MESSAGE 'Domain not found' TYPE 'E'.
    ENDIF.
  ENDIF.

  IF convexit IS NOT INITIAL.
    SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM dd01l
        UP TO 1 ROWS
        WHERE convexit = @convexit.
    IF sy-subrc <> 0.
      MESSAGE 'Conversion exit not found' TYPE 'E'.
    ENDIF.
  ENDIF.

  IF extvalue IS NOT INITIAL.
    IF lowercase = abap_false.
      TRANSLATE extvalue TO UPPER CASE.
    ENDIF.
    IF strlen( extvalue ) > outputlen.
      MESSAGE |Value must be { outputlen } characters max| TYPE 'E'.
    ENDIF.
  ELSE.
    IF strlen( intvalue ) > leng.
      MESSAGE |Value must be { leng } characters max| TYPE 'E'.
    ENDIF.
    SELECT SINGLE dd04l~rollname
        FROM dd04l
        INNER JOIN dd01l
          ON dd04l~domname = dd01l~domname
        WHERE dd01l~convexit = @convexit
        INTO @DATA(dd04l_rollname).
    IF sy-subrc <> 0.
      MESSAGE 'Domain has no data element' TYPE 'E'.
    ENDIF.
    DATA dref TYPE REF TO data.
    CREATE DATA dref TYPE (dd04l_rollname).
    ASSIGN dref->* TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<intvalue>).
    TRY.
        <intvalue> = intvalue.
        DATA(back_intvalue) = CONV string( <intvalue> ).
        IF NOT back_intvalue CS intvalue.
          MESSAGE 'Invalid internal value for given domain' TYPE 'E'.
        ENDIF.
        intvalue = <intvalue>.
      CATCH cx_sy_conversion_error.
        MESSAGE 'Invalid internal value for given domain' TYPE 'E'.
    ENDTRY.
  ENDIF.

START-OF-SELECTION.

  DATA(max_rows_bis) = COND i( WHEN max_rows > 0 THEN max_rows + 1 ).
  SELECT swotdv~objtype,
         tojtb~editelem  AS objtype_id,
         tojtt~stext     AS objtype_stext,
         tojtt~ntext     AS objtype_ntext,
         swotdv~editelem AS method,
         swotdq~editelem AS parameter,
         dd03l~fieldname AS field,
         swotdq~reffield AS swotdq_reffield,
         dd01l~convexit
      FROM swotdv
        INNER JOIN tojtb
          ON tojtb~name       = swotdv~objtype
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tojtt
          ON tojtt~name       = tojtb~name
         AND tojtt~language   = @sy-langu
        INNER JOIN swotdq
          ON swotdq~objtype   = swotdv~objtype
         AND swotdq~verb      = swotdv~verb
        INNER JOIN dd03l
          ON dd03l~tabname    = swotdq~refstruct
        INNER JOIN dd01l
          ON dd01l~domname    = dd03l~domname
      WHERE tojtb~active     = 'X'
        AND swotdq~paramtype = 'M'
        AND dd01l~convexit   = @convexit
        AND swotdv~objtype  IN @s_objtyp
        AND tojtb~editelem  IN @s_objid
        AND tojtt~stext     IN @s_objstx
        AND tojtt~ntext     IN @s_objntx
        AND swotdv~editelem IN @s_method
        AND swotdq~editelem IN @s_param
        AND ( swotdq~reffield = ' '
           OR swotdq~reffield = dd03l~fieldname )
        AND dd03l~fieldname IN @s_field
      INTO TABLE @DATA(fields)
      UP TO @max_rows_bis ROWS.

  TYPES ty_bapi_conversion_direction TYPE c LENGTH 7.
  TYPES ty_bapi_conversion_calls TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_bapi_conversion_direction WITH EMPTY KEY.
  DATA(bapi_conversion_calls) = VALUE ty_bapi_conversion_calls( ).
  DATA(intvalue_2) = VALUE bapiconvrs-int_format( ).
  DATA(extvalue_2) = VALUE bapiconvrs-ext_format( ).

  bapi_conversion_calls = VALUE #( ( 'EXT2INT' ) ( 'INT2EXT' ) ).

  DATA(lo_grid) = NEW cl_salv_form_layout_grid( ).
  lo_grid->add_row( )->create_text( text = |Table:           { tabname }| ).
  lo_grid->add_row( )->create_text( text = |Field (column):  { fieldnam }| ).
  lo_grid->add_row( )->create_text( text = |Data element:    { rollname }| ).
  lo_grid->add_row( )->create_text( text = |Domain:          { domname }| ).
  lo_grid->add_row( )->create_text( text = |Conversion exit: { convexit }| ).
  lo_grid->add_row( )->create_text( text = |Internal length: { leng }| ).
  lo_grid->add_row( )->create_text( text = |External length: { outputlen }| ).
  lo_grid->add_row( ).
  IF extvalue IS NOT INITIAL.
    bapi_conversion_calls = VALUE #( ( 'EXT2INT' ) ( 'INT2EXT' ) ).
    lo_grid->add_row( )->create_text( text = |Start value (external): { extvalue }| ).
    lo_grid->add_row( ).
  ELSE.
    bapi_conversion_calls = VALUE #( ( 'INT2EXT' ) ( 'EXT2INT' ) ).
    lo_grid->add_row( )->create_text( text = |Start value (internal): { intvalue }| ).
    lo_grid->add_row( ).
  ENDIF.
  IF max_rows <> 0
      AND lines( fields ) > max_rows.
    lo_grid->add_row( )->create_header_information(
        text = |More results can be displayed by increasing MAX_ROWS > { max_rows }| ).
    DELETE fields INDEX max_rows + 1.
  ENDIF.

  TYPES:
    BEGIN OF ty_alv_line,
      objtype        TYPE swotdv-objtype,
      method         TYPE swotdv-editelem,
      parameter      TYPE swotdq-editelem,
      field          TYPE dd03l-fieldname,
      objtype_id     TYPE tojtb-editelem,
      objtype_stext  TYPE tojtt-stext,
      objtype_ntext  TYPE tojtt-ntext,
      extvalue_2     TYPE bapiconvrs-ext_format,
      external_error TYPE string,
      intvalue_2     TYPE bapiconvrs-int_format,
      internal_error TYPE string,
      diff_error     TYPE string,
    END OF ty_alv_line.
  TYPES ty_alv_table TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_alv_line WITH EMPTY KEY.
  DATA(alv_table) = VALUE ty_alv_table( ).

  LOOP AT fields REFERENCE INTO DATA(ref_field).

    DATA(alv_line) = VALUE ty_alv_line( ).

    alv_line-objtype   = ref_field->objtype.
    alv_line-objtype_id     = ref_field->objtype_id.
    alv_line-objtype_stext  = ref_field->objtype_stext.
    alv_line-objtype_ntext  = ref_field->objtype_ntext.
    alv_line-method    = ref_field->method.
    alv_line-parameter = ref_field->parameter.
    alv_line-field     = COND #( WHEN ref_field->swotdq_reffield IS INITIAL THEN ref_field->field ).

    TYPES tt_data TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF bapiconvrs WITH EMPTY KEY.

    DATA(lt_data) = VALUE tt_data( ).
    DATA(lt_return) = VALUE bapirettab( ).

    IF extvalue IS NOT INITIAL.
      extvalue_2 = extvalue.
    ELSE.
      intvalue_2 = intvalue.
    ENDIF.

    LOOP AT bapi_conversion_calls REFERENCE INTO DATA(bapi_conversion_call).

      CASE bapi_conversion_call->*.
        WHEN 'EXT2INT'.
          lt_data = VALUE #(
            ( objtype    = ref_field->objtype
              method     = ref_field->method
              parameter  = ref_field->parameter
              field      = ref_field->field
              "rownumber  = 0
              "int_format = ''
              ext_format = extvalue_2
              "conv_len   = 0
              ) ).

          CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_CONVERSION_EXT2INT1'
            TABLES
              data   = lt_data
              return = lt_return.

          intvalue_2 = lt_data[ 1 ]-int_format.
          alv_line-internal_error = COND #( WHEN lt_return IS NOT INITIAL
                                    THEN 'Error in BAPI_CONVERSION_EXT2INT1' ).

        WHEN 'INT2EXT'.
          lt_data = VALUE #(
            ( objtype    = ref_field->objtype
              method     = ref_field->method
              parameter  = ref_field->parameter
              field      = ref_field->field
              "rownumber  = 0
              int_format = intvalue_2
              "ext_format = ''
              "conv_len   = 0
              ) ).
          lt_return = VALUE #( ).

          CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_CONVERSION_INT2EXT1'
            TABLES
              data   = lt_data
              return = lt_return.

          extvalue_2 = lt_data[ 1 ]-ext_format.
          alv_line-external_error = COND #( WHEN lt_return IS NOT INITIAL
                                    THEN 'Error in BAPI_CONVERSION_INT2EXT1' ).
      ENDCASE.

    ENDLOOP.

    alv_line-diff_error = COND #( WHEN ( extvalue IS NOT INITIAL
                            AND extvalue_2 <> extvalue )
                           OR ( extvalue IS INITIAL
                            AND intvalue_2 <> intvalue )
                 THEN 'The final value is different from the Start value').

    alv_line-intvalue_2 = intvalue_2.
    alv_line-extvalue_2 = extvalue_2.

    INSERT alv_line INTO TABLE alv_table.
  ENDLOOP.

  cl_salv_table=>factory( IMPORTING r_salv_table = DATA(gr_table)
                          CHANGING  t_table = alv_table ).
  gr_table->get_functions( )->set_all( ).
  DATA(gr_columns) = gr_table->get_columns( ).
  gr_columns->set_optimize( ).
  gr_columns->get_column( 'EXTVALUE_2' )->set_fixed_header_text( 'L' ).
  gr_columns->get_column( 'EXTVALUE_2' )->set_long_text( 'Result of INT->EXT' ).
  gr_columns->get_column( 'INTVALUE_2' )->set_fixed_header_text( 'L' ).
  gr_columns->get_column( 'INTVALUE_2' )->set_long_text( 'Result of EXT->INT' ).
  IF extvalue IS NOT INITIAL.
    " New column sequence INT then EXT: INTVALUE_2, INTERNAL_ERROR, EXTVALUE_2, EXTERNAL_ERROR
    " (instead of EXT then INT: EXTVALUE_2, EXTERNAL_ERROR, INTVALUE_2, INTERNAL_ERROR)
    gr_columns->set_column_position( columnname = 'INTERNAL_ERROR' position = 8 ).
    gr_columns->set_column_position( columnname = 'INTVALUE_2' position = 8 ).
  ENDIF.
  gr_table->set_top_of_list( lo_grid ).
  gr_table->display( ).
```

Here are the screen field values to find parameters of `BAPI_CONVERSION_INT2EXT1` to get the external value from the internal value `00000106` of the column `PS_PSP_PNR` of the table `VBAP` (note that the `S_OBJTYP` field is optional and has been set only to simplify the result):

[image: Input to find parameter values for BAPI_CONVERSION_INT2EXT1]

Here is the result (each row is one possibility of BAPI parameter values and the BAPI parameters are grouped in the left columns):

[image: Result of possible parameter values for BAPI_CONVERSION_INT2EXT1]

It means that `BAPI_CONVERSION_INT2EXT1` may be called for instance with these parameters:

- OBJTYPE = "BUS2031001"
- METHOD = "GetDetailBos"
- PARAMETER = "QuotationHeader"
- FIELD = "WBS_ELEM"
- INT_FORMAT = "00000106"

### 2) If you know the Business Object Type

The diagram sequence below shows the screenshots of `SWO1` transaction code.

First, you need to find the business object type corresponding to the WBS Project via the search help (`F4`), which is `BUS2054`.

The BAPI method name is `GetInfo` (which corresponds to `BAPI_PROJECT_GETINFO` if you look into the details of the method).

The parameters you need are `ProjectDefinition` and `EWbsElementTable`.

By looking at the details of the parameters, you may know if it's a single value/no compound fields (`ProjectDefinition`) or a structure or table made of many fields (`EWbsElementTable`).

You may obtain the **External value** of the WBS Element in the **field** `WBS_ELEMENT` of the parameter `EWbsElementTable`.

[image: SWO1 How to get the Method, Parameter and Field for BAPI_CONVERSION_EXT2INT1]

## Example of ABAP implementation with both `BAPI_CONVERSION_INT2EXT1` and `BAPI_CONVERSION_EXT2INT1`

Now that you know all the technical names, you may create the program. I hope the explanations given above are sufficient to understand the program.

```
REPORT.

TYPES tt_data TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF bapiconvrs WITH EMPTY KEY.
TYPES ty_export_wbs_element_table TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF bapi_wbs_element_exp  WITH EMPTY KEY.

*   Data type      External value     Interval value
*   -----------    ---------------    ------------------
*   Project        I.001              I 001000   000  00
*   WBS element    I.0011             I0011000   000  00

DATA(lt_data) = VALUE tt_data(
  ( objtype    = 'BUS2054'
    method     = 'Getinfo'
    parameter  = 'ProjectDefinition'
    "field      = ''
    "rownumber  = 0
    int_format = 'I 001000   000  00'
    "ext_format = ''
    "conv_len   = 0
    ) ).
DATA(lt_return) = VALUE bapirettab( ).

CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_CONVERSION_INT2EXT1'
  TABLES
    data   = lt_data
    return = lt_return.

WRITE : / 'Project internal value', lt_data[ 1 ]-int_format. " 'I 001000   000  00'
WRITE : / 'Project external value', lt_data[ 1 ]-ext_format. " e.g. possibly contains 'I.001'

DATA(project_definition) = CONV ps_pspid( lt_data[ 1 ]-ext_format ).
DATA(e_project_definition) = VALUE bapi_project_definition_ex( ).
DATA(ls_return) = VALUE bapireturn1( ).
DATA(e_wbs_element_table) = VALUE ty_export_wbs_element_table( ).
CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_PROJECT_GETINFO'
  EXPORTING
    project_definition   = project_definition
  IMPORTING
    e_project_definition = e_project_definition
    return               = ls_return
  TABLES
    e_wbs_element_table  = e_wbs_element_table.

IF ls_return IS NOT INITIAL.
  WRITE : / 'Error:', ls_return.
ELSE.

  WRITE : / 'Success, project description is', e_project_definition-description.

  LOOP AT e_wbs_element_table REFERENCE INTO DATA(wbs_element).

    lt_data = VALUE #(
      ( objtype    = 'BUS2054'
        method     = 'Getinfo'
        parameter  = 'EWbsElementTable'
        field      = 'WBS_ELEMENT'
        rownumber  = sy-tabix " the line number in e_wbs_element_table
        "int_format = ''
        ext_format = wbs_element->wbs_element
        "conv_len   = 0
        ) ).

    CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_CONVERSION_EXT2INT1'
      TABLES
        data   = lt_data
        return = lt_return.

    DATA(text_ext) = 'external value'.
    WRITE : / 'WBS element:', text_ext, lt_data[ 1 ]-ext_format. " e.g. contains 'I.0011'
    WRITE : / 'internal value' UNDER text_ext, lt_data[ 1 ]-int_format. " e.g. contains 'I0011000   000  00'

  ENDLOOP.

ENDIF.
```

Output:

[image: ABAP SAP ERP WBS Element and Project Internal and External values]

NB 1: direct call of `BAPI_CONVERSION_INT2EXT1` via `SE37`:

[image: SE37 BAPI_CONVERSION_INT2EXT1]

NB 2: WBS = Work Breakdown Structure, and is part of the PS (Project System) module of SAP ERP and S/4HANA software.

Comment: Thank you for you big explanation, but I still cannot get this to work. Maybe I am also completely wrong. But e.g. in table "VBAP" exists a column "PS_PSP_PNR" and I looked for a way to convert this internal number into an external number. Is there some other way to do it except using this BAPI? I also don't know how to find a row number, I just have the internal PSP number...
Maybe my problem is that I don't code in SAP directly but use the RFC API from Java.

Comment: You "cannot get this to work", but what did you try? "RFC API from Java" = JCo 3.x? There's no reason to have an issue related to JCo. This BAPI is well suited for your need. If it doesn't work, it's due to something specific to your code or to the SAP data. Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question.

Comment: I updated the question with what I tried. Just INT2EXT in the question, but getting EXT2INT to work with your other parameters just led to being the internal value the same as the external value.
The API is autogenerated from the SAP metadata and just a wrapper I use for dozens of other BAPIs already so I don't have to remember the field names in Java, but it's essentially JCo 3.1.

Comment: It would be most relatable for me if your would be able to call the BAPI with se37 and show the values you enter there, because this seems to resemble JCo the most.

Comment: You didn't understand my answer. The issue with your code is that you have converted the WBS Element code as being a Project (`ProjectDefinition`) instead of a WBS Element (`parameter  = 'EWbsElementTable' field = 'WBS_ELEMENT'). I will clarify my answer which I guess is not clear enough.

Comment: Ok, I changed the parameters in my question which is a bit misleading because my usecase there does int2ext while I originally spoke about ext2int, but also when I use  EWbsElementTable and WBS_ELEMENT I still only receive the internal value in the EXT_FORMAT field. But really, please typ se37 and tell me which BAPIs you are calling there to convert the internal number like 102882 to e.g. "REP_S01588 0001". Sorry I don't get it better, without ABAP knowledge this is hard to grasp.

Comment: I added a bountry for your work to motivate you to get this running for me :).

Comment: Got it, we're not talking about the same WBS Element number, you're talking about `PRPS-PSPNR` (internal value of 8 numeric digits) while I'm on `PRPS-POSID` (internal value of 24 characters). Let me add a little time to elaborate the answer in a third chapter. NB: Thanks but no motivation needed. Screenshot added for `SE37`. ABAP developers know that ABAP code is better than `SE37` which may give wrong or misleading results due to invalid data types and few other reasons (but not for this one).

Comment: I edited the answer with the solution for you (chapter VBAP-PS_PSP_NR). I'll update it later to include more details (need investigating).

Comment: Thank you so much, the new parameters worked as expected. Thanks!

Comment: Investigation is over, answer updated by providing an enriched ABAP program. Unfortunately, people who don't have access to ABAP will have to ask an ABAP developer and ask to execute this ABAP program.